# Updating progress bar in react js, while inserting data into database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I want the progress bar in react js to be updating parallelly while inserting data into the database. Backend I have been using is spring boot, I want to update the progress bar, till the endpoint from my controller from the server sends status  200.

My requirement was to insert an array of objects into the database, say more than 100 objects, meanwhile, the progress bar has to be updated until all the objects are inserted into the db.

This is my client-side code

```
class UploadMultiPleFiles extends React.Component{

    constructor()
   {
       super();
       this.state={
           fileArr:[],
           progress:0,
       }


   }
   

   changeFile=(event)=>{
       const filedata=event.target.files;

        var arr=[];
        if(filedata.length!==0)
        {
           for(let i=0;i<filedata.length;i++)
           { 
            var obj={}
            obj.name=filedata[i].name;
            obj.type=filedata[i].type;
            arr.push(obj);
            
    
           }
        }
       
        this.setState({
            fileArr:arr
        })

        console.log(obj);
        console.log(this.state.fileArr)
         }


   upload=()=>
   {
       let currentFile=this.state.selectedFiles[0];
       this.setState({
           progress:0,
           currentFile:currentFile,
       });
       let formData=new FormData();
       formData.append("file",currentFile);


   }
   


  onFileSubmit=(e)=>{
     
   e.preventDefault();
        axios({method:'post',
        data: this.state.fileArr,
        url:'http://localhost:8080/postList',
        onUploadProgress:(ev:ProgressEvent)=>{
        const progress=((ev.loaded*100)/ev.total);
        this.setState(
            {
                progress:progress
            }
        )
        console.log(progress)
        }
    }
         ).then((res)=>{
             console.log(res.status)
         })
  }


    render()
    {
        return(
            <Container>
                <h1>Upload Multiple Files</h1>
<Form style={{paddingTop:10}} onSubmit={this.onFileSubmit} className="mt-1">
     <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
       
       <Form.Control type="file" size="lg" name="file" onChange={this.changeFile} multiple/>
        
     </Form.Group>  
     <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit Files</Button>
     </Form>
     <h4>Files which are uploaded </h4>
     <ProgressBar now={this.state.progress}/>

    <Table className="mt-1" variant="dark" striped bordered hover  size="sm"  style={{paddingLeft:100}} > 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th>File Type</th>
       
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
                {this.state.fileArr.map(c =>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{c.name}</td>
                    <td>{c.type}</td>

                  </tr>
                )}
              </tbody>

    </Table>

            </Container>
            
        );
    }
   

}
```

Backend code in spring boot

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping("/postList")
    public void pushData(@RequestBody List<FileUpload> fileUploads)
    {
        opservice.saveAllFiles(fileUploads);
    }
    }
```

Model class

```
@Entity

public class FileUpload {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    
    private String name;
    
    private String type;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    

    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Adding question mark to end of a sentence doesn't make it a question. Formulate a question + what you have tried + what you are getting stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

i've done something like that by implementing spring-websocket (https://github.com/fajaralmu/base_web_app and more repos...)
step:

1. configure websocket in backend(spring) and client
2. send the progress to client in some point of the backend process so the client can show the realtime progress